# DataTables Individual column search boxes conflicting with colvis

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I AM  using 1.10.9 version ,I have more than 70 columns and I am using ajax to load data so instead to writing th tag for all I use a for loop but when iam making columns invisible by using colvis the search boxes are not going invisible . links i  refered https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

```
        code is here ..

          $(document).ready( function () {        

     var table;

     table= $('#example).DataTable( {



                "processing": true,

                "deferRender": true,

                //"searching": true,

                //"serverSide": true,                   

                 dom: 'BRlfrtip',

                 buttons: [

                            {  extend: 'colvis',

                                text: 'Change Layout',

                                collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column'

                            }                     

                         ],             



                 "ajax": {

                            "url": "/example.so",

                            "type": "GET"

                             },
"columns": [{

            "title": "name",

            "data": "name",

            "name": "name"

        }, {

            "title": "city",

            "data": "city",

            "name": "city"

        }]

    });
         var noofcolumn= $('#example thead th').length;
                                        colmn="";

                                        for(i=0; i<noofcolumn; i++)
                                        {
                                        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( i ).text();
                                        colmn+='<th><input type="text" placeholder="Search" /></th>';
                                        }
                                        $('#example tfoot').html( colmn );

                                     // Apply the search

                                        table.columns().every( function ()
                                                {
                                        $('input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                                            table
                                                .column( $(this).parent().index()+':visible' )
                                                .search( this.value )
                                                .draw();

                                        } );                
                            });
```

in end here just simple html tags closed.   table id,thead,tfoot div. not using any td or th  here.

Comment: Please include your full code where you show/hide columns.

Comment: yes i updated the post. does it make sense now ?

Comment: I have posted an answer, does it work for you?

Comment: your solution looks fine but in my case i am using a ajax to load the data and also i am not writing th tr tags in html code , so in that case i need for loop and that for loop i cant put before initializing table. how can i hide textbox with hiding column which texbox i genereated by loop by counting no. of columns .

Comment: If you're not using server-side processing, you can retrieve the data first with jQuery `$.ajax` method and then construct text boxes and only then initialize datatable with the data received from the server.

Comment: you mean just shifting the code snippets like ajax and loop before table initialzation?

Comment: Can you give me a more clear view please ? how should  i  shift the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

- You needed to construct `thead` element before initializing the table.
- You needed to wrap all `th` elements in `tr` element when generating text inputs in footer.

[Individual column searching example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) has much simpler implementation of text input generation so I used that instead.

> **DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready( function () { 
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } ); 
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
           {  
              extend: 'colvis',
              text: 'Change Layout',
              collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column'
           }                     
        ]
    });
  

    // Apply the search

    table.columns().every(function () {
        $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
            table.column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                .search(this.value)
                .draw();

        });
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.colvis-group-show,
.colvis-group-hide {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.colvis-group-show {
  display:none;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://nightly.datatables.net/buttons/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
    
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$4,525</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ebony Grimes</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Russell Chavez</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Unity Butler</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/12/09</td>
            <td>$3,750</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/12/16</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2010/02/12</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2008/12/11</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>2008/09/26</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Miriam Weiss</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2011/02/03</td>
            <td>$4,965</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>2011/05/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Odessa Jackson</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2009/08/19</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Thor Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2013/08/11</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/07/07</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Elton Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2012/04/09</td>
            <td>$6,730</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2010/01/04</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>56</td>
            <td>2012/06/01</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2013/02/01</td>
            <td>$2,875</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/12/06</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2011/03/21</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lael Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Shad Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$4,080</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Gyrocode Can you give me a more clear view please ? how should i shift the code